# OneDrive folder not syncing despite removing from roaming profile

Tags: windows-8.1, sync, windows-server-2012, onedrive

I'm in a small business running Windows Server Essentials 2012 r2 on a headless server with Windows 8.1 clients.

I've had various problems syncing OneDrive, which appeared to be solved by removing SkyDrive and OneDrive from my Roaming Profile with a group policy. I have used 'gpupdate /Force' on all affected PC's. This now works great on my Windows 8.1 Pro tablet - both SkyDrive and my Roaming Profile sync nicely.

On my Win 8.1 Pro desktop, however, it does not. The OneDrive app says it is unable to open the OneDrive location. The MS troubleshooter tool still complains that this is due to my roaming profile.

Deleting the SkyDrive folder manually and then re-creating it appears to work well - until I reboot and the same problem occurs again. Obviously deleting the folder manually each time I reboot is a bit of a pain.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I realise there are third party sync apps, but I'd rather use Windows' own version if possible.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have [compatibility issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaming_user_profile#Compatibility) trying to sync a roaming profile from Windows Server 2012 with Windows 8.1. Perhaps you can sync specific folders between machines (desktop, documents, pictures, videos) instead of a roaming profile.

Answer (score 1):

**Revised Answer:**
Install [SyncDriver](http://syncdriver.com/).

**Original Answer:**

If you navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SkyDrive in the registry, and then add your OneDrive folder path under a string of "UserFolder", it will sync on Windows 8.1, with a roaming profile, as it just did for me.

**Source**:
*Literally* just got it working myself.

**Edit**:
It worked, but only for one glorious login to my profile.
I just installed SyncDriver instead, which is much more effective in any case.

Comment: So what is your answer?

Comment: My answer CURRENTLY is to just use SyncDriver, but I've apparently developed OCD for this issue, so I'm looking into a couple of other fixes that are supposed to work.

So, stay tuned, I guess?

Comment: I tried a number of additional solutions, but the OneDrive app has officially become too much effort for me, given that there are more effective alternatives.